# undefined method `comments' Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Итак у меня вылазит ошибка, при создании комментария к посту

Comments Controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

   def create
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = Post.comments.create(comment_params)
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
   end

   private def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:username, :body)
   end
end
```

Post rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :comments
   validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
end
```

Миграцию сделал, но всё-равно выводит ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас ошибка в коде, Вы пытаетесь вызвать comments у класса Post, нужно вызывать у инстанса, который лежит в @post